# Django: How to set EDT timezone in settings for Florida

Tags: python, django, datetime

I want to set Django timezone so that clock should remain consistent with local time in Florida, which is Eastern+Daylight Savings Time (DST). Please suggest the changes to the Django settings timezone such that it is consistent with this time zone; currently the django is set for EST (Eastern Standard Time) rather than EDT (Eastern Daylight Time). It should automatically change when we enter/leave DST.

```
# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
```

I am running my application in amazon ubuntu. What is the best time_zone to use for Florida local time. I am using Django 1.5.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Correct timezone name (from tz database) for Florida is "America/New_York", simply put that into your `TIME_ZONE` setting instead of "America/Chicago"

Comment: Daylight saving time is applied automatically, so the answer is: yes, it will help you permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of time zones along with their string values:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Setting it to `America/New_York` will cover most eastern states. Refer to the wikipedia for a list of all possible options.